# Extract string between by [" "]

Tags: java, regex, string, jmeter

how can I extract string between `[" "]`
I have eg: `["x"]`, so how can I extract just `x` and assign it to a 
variable
I have tried this:

```
String str = "[x]";    
String result = str.substring(str.indexOf("[") + 1, str.indexOf("]"));
```

I can get x using the above code but my string is enclosed between `[" "]`

Comment: Do you need to use regex or can u just replace [" and "] with ""

Comment: @farrellmr the string is between `[" "]` not just `" "`

Comment: i meant empty string "[x]".replace("[", "").replace("]", ""); produces x

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be the following:

```
String s = "aaaa [\"axas\"]";
String result = s.substring(s.indexOf("[\"")+2, s.indexOf("\"]"));
```

`\"` stands for a character `"` - `\` is an escape character and it is the missing part in your solution.

[image]

results in:

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine. but in my situation, x is a json object which I am extracting using json path extractor in jmeter and the result when extracted is `name=["x"]`. So how can I append those `/` since the result I get when extracted is in this pattern `["x"]` only

Answer (score 0):

This regexp seems to work:

```
final String regexpStr = "\\[\"(.*?)\"\\]";
```

JUnit test for it:

```
@Test
public void regexp() {
    final String[] noMatch = { "", "[", "[\"", "]", "\"]", "\"[", "]\"", "asdf",
            "[\"asdfasdf\"", "asdf[sadf\"asdf\"]" };
    final String[] match = { "[\"one\"]", "asdf[\"one\"]", "[\"one\"]asdf", "asdf[\"one\"]asdf",
            "asdf[\"one\"]asdf[\"two\"]asdf" };
    final String regexpStr = "\\[\"(.*?)\"\\]";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexpStr);
    for (final String s : noMatch) {
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
        Assert.assertFalse(m.matches());
    }

    for (final String s : match) {
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
        Assert.assertTrue(m.find());
        Assert.assertEquals(m.group(1), "one");
        if (m.find()) {
            Assert.assertEquals(m.group(1), "two");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package soquestion;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SOQuestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "[\"foo\"] and [\"bar\"]";
        System.out.println("String is: " + str);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\\"(.*?)\\\"\\]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Result: " + m.group(1));
        }            
    }

}
```

Results in:

```
String is: ["foo"] and ["bar"]
Result: foo
Result: bar
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String in = "[ABC]";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. It's quotes within brackets. You did the other way around. :)